# "placeholder" da "textarea" não aparece

Tags: html5, placeholder, textarea

Tenho uma `textarea` com um `placeholder` que de acordo com a [documentação](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/textarea) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> é perfeitamente válido e deveria funcionar:

[**Exemplo no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/hD5j6/)

### Parte do formulário

```php
<?php

/* Apenas o código referente à textarea
 */
$oc_message = isset($postArr["oc_message"]) ? cleanStr($postArr["oc_message"]) : '';

$form = '
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="oc_message">
        '.ucfirst(I18N_WORD_MESSAGE).' <small class="text-danger">*</small>
    </label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="oc_message" name="oc_message" placeholder="'.I18N_PLACEHOLDER_MESSAGE.'" rows="10">
       '.$oc_message.'
    </textarea>
</div>';
?>
```

No entanto, o texto do `placeholder` não aparece na mesma!

### HTML gerado:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="oc_message">
        Mensagem 
        <small class="text-danger">*</small>
    </label>
    <textarea rows="10" placeholder="Introduza a sua mensagem" name="oc_message" id="oc_message" class="form-control">                          
    </textarea>
</div>
```

## Pergunta

Porque é que o `placeholder` não está a aparecer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O problema é que o *placeholder* aparece apenas quando o *textarea* está vazio, sem texto algum. O seu não está, você inseriu os espaços da identação nele.

Experimente:

```html
<form action="" method="post">
    <div>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="A sua mensagem"></textarea>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Como ambas as respostas falam do mesmo, fica esta aceite por ter sido colocada primeiro.

Answer (score 6):

No caso da tag `textarea`, para o `placeholder` funcionar, a abertura e fecho da tag têm de estar na mesma linha e sem espaços.

No seu caso a `textarea` pensa que a quebra de linha é conteúdo e o `placeholder` não aparece.

#### Assim deve-se usar:

```html
<textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="A sua mensagem"></textarea>
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6z45J/)

Comment: Comigo, funcionoa se eu coloco o fechamento (`>`) da tag e a abertura do final dela na mesma linha tb.